# PL-SQL Bulk Collect after execute immediate statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to execute bellow statement but I think the sintax is not right. Is it possible to use bulk collect after execute immediate??

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
        'select unique cvc.object_id ' ||
        'from ems.ibo_sm_cvc_rfs cvc,' || 
        'ems.ibo_alcatel_mse_locale poi,' ||
        'ems.ibo_nbn_csa csa,' ||
        'ems.ibo_sm_ean_service_sites_rfs sites,' ||
        'EMS.ibo_sm_ean_service_site_rfs site ' ||
        'where poi.object_name = :1' 
         USING pis_poi_for_cleanup
         BULK COLLECT INTO pona_identified_cvcs;
```

The error I'm getting is generic:

> Encountered the symbol "BULK" when expecting one of the following: ...

Comment: Try moving the `USING` part ***after*** the `BULK COLLECT` part of your statement.

Comment: That was it, thanks, should have look better on the web. Thanks

Comment: You should add it as an answer @sstan since it is the question solver for the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewriting the original answer, move the `USING` clause after the `BULK COLLECT` statement:

```
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select unique cvc.object_id ' ||
        'from ems.ibo_sm_cvc_rfs cvc,' || 
        'ems.ibo_alcatel_mse_locale poi,' ||
        'ems.ibo_nbn_csa csa,' ||
        'ems.ibo_sm_ean_service_sites_rfs sites,' ||
        'EMS.ibo_sm_ean_service_site_rfs site ' ||
        'where poi.object_name = :1'
        BULK COLLECT INTO pona_identified_cvcs
        USING pis_poi_for_cleanup;
END;
/
```

You could extend this code reviewing this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#i18972).

Hope this help!!!

Comment: Links are fragile. If there's some wisdom to be found at the other end of a link, you can do future searchers a massive favour and detail the key points in your answer, in addition to linking the original source, of course.

Comment: I'm the kind type of person :), took into consideration this answer as the solution  but also looked deeper because my code is larger and need so.